# Call web server using django

Tags: django

I would like to know how could I call a web server using django. Oaths server there is a application called appExaple:

the web server is: example.si.eus
And the application I want to use on the django framework is: appExample

I'm new at django, so please, be patient with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will handle incoming web requests - i.e. other people calling your server.

If you want to make calls to other server then the Python Requests framework is very good. It is completely independent from Django, but will work from within your Django code.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/